# How to pull data from Facebook hash with multiple entries with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have used OmniAuth to connect with Facebook. I am pulling various pieces of information and have no problem pulling information where there is only one type of it. For example, to get the email address, I just place the following in user.rb:

```
user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
```

The problem is with multiple entries. For example, for education, there are two results. One is a High School named Punahou School while the other is a College named University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign.

```
education: 
    - !map:Hashie::Mash 
      school: !map:Hashie::Mash 
        id: "105510192816251"
        name: Punahou School
      type: High School
    - !map:Hashie::Mash 
      school: !map:Hashie::Mash 
        id: "163536409904"
        name: University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign
      type: College
```

I was able to pull the first school using:

```
if auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"]
    user.school = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][0]["school"]["name"]
end
```

The problem with this is, it only pulls the first school which is the high school. I have a couple of questions here:

1. If I only want the College, how would I get it to pull University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign? If there is a high school and college, I would want the code to only pick up whatever school is the college.
2. Now, let's say I want both the high school and college. How would I pull both and how would I mark that Punahou is the high school and UIUC is the college?
3. If there are multiple colleges, how would I pull the most recent college entry?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar question with OmniAuth and LinkedIn, came across your question and it helped me come up with a solution. LinkedIn's hash returns the three current positions in a form similar to Facebook's behavior above. Change `[0]` to `[1]` and it will pull the college in your example. Use separate lines for each entry you want. I found the LinkedIn hash returned the three current positions in order with the most recent entry being in the `[0]` position.